# How to sort aggregations in elasticsearch by fields other than _term?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have indexed a list of songs data in Elasticsearch, like,

```
    {ID:1, Title:Bailamos,      Genre:Pop,      Artist:Enrique},
    {ID:2, Title:Ring of Fire,  Genre:Country,  Artist:Johnny Cash},
    {ID:3, Title:Free Bird,     Genre:Country,  Artist:Lynyrd Skynyrd},
    {ID:4, Title:Immigrant Song,Genre:Rock,     Artist:Led Zeppelin},
    {ID:5, Title:Jump,          Genre:Rock,     Artist:Van Helen}
```

Now I need to group the songs according to their particular genre. So, it will be shown as:

```
    Country -   2 songs,
    Rock    -   2 songs,
    Pop     -   1 song
```

Currently, I am using aggregations to get this result.

```
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_all": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "SongGroups": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Genre",
            "size": 10,
            "order":{
                "_score":"asc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_Song_hits": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "Title": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Now the problem is, I need to sort the genre groups by other fields, like 'Title' or 'Artist'. The genre groups should be sorted according to the field data of the first matching song of that genre.

For example, if I sort by Artist, the result should come as :

```
    Pop     -   1 song   (since first artist is Enrique)
    Country -   2 songs, (since first artist is Johnny Cash)
    Rock    -   2 songs, (since first artist is Led Zeppelin)
```

But, I found out that sorting by field in aggregations is not supported in Elasticsearch.
So, is there any way I can achieve this in a single call to Elasticsearch? Or is there any other work-around through which I can achieve the desired results? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide guys.

PS. There also will be pagination applied if the list is large.

Comment: If you want to make just a single call, the best you can do according to me is to sub aggregate on artist name, and then use just the topmost result from the sub-aggregation to sort results at application level.

Comment: yes @rajat it will work if I sort at application level, but pagination wont work out then. Again, taking out all the documents in a single call for paginating at application level will be a costly operation performance wise. I want to avoid that.